# Angular schematics Tree: how to exclude?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I've got a Tree whose root is the project root dir.

I would like to apply a rule using forEach, which iterates through all the files in the tree. This works, but it's very slow since node_modules is also part of the tree.

How could I exclude that dir?

I tried:

```
 const templateSource = apply(source(tree), [
            filter(path => {
                return !path.includes('node_modules');
            }),

            forEach((entry: FileEntry) => {
            ....
            }
```

But this always fails:

> Error: Path "/some/path/some.file" already exist.

I don't see any methods which could help me to branch off the tree or something like that. I need to apply the forEach to only part of the tree. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are trying to create a file that is already exists.
use strategy.override.

```
if (tree.exists(file.path)) tree.overwrite(file.path, file.content);
```

Comment: The strategies don't seem to do anything. I mean, overwrite, allowCreateConflict and the rest appear to be simply ignored. Schematics still complains about existing files.

Comment: Use tree.exists and tree.override methods